# Why didn't Masashi Miyamoto take Taira's chip after cutting his fingers?

Tags: btooom

In episode 7 "Virtual bride" of Btooom [Masashi](http://myanimelist.net/character/66323/Masashi_Miyamoto) attacked [Taira](http://myanimelist.net/character/67473/Kiyoshi_Taira) with his knife and cut his fingers off. He then caused Sakamoto to fall of the cliff and he kidnapped Himiko.

Why didn't he take Taira's chip? Why was he left alive?

Answer (score 1):

You could say it is a plot hole. At that point, I don't know why he didn't kill them right there and then.

You could look at it as a typical case of "Bond Villain" where the baddie has to set a challenge/trap for the protagonist without actually killing the girl because it allows the story to continue, and without it your cast of characters thins out, thus ending the story.

**Most importantly** - *in my opinion* - The original author was also building that underlying Taira

> betrayal

story so he can't have him dying just yet.

Comment: I haven't watched that episode but I have read the manga. In the manga, after Masashi kicked Sakamoto, Taira threaten Masashi with his homing BIM. Masashi then said that he would wait till Taira died because of loss of blood and came back to claim the chip.